# HTC & Motorola Emulator

Tags: android

I made an Android application.The Application is mainly of Tracing.I tested the application on Samsung Galaxy Grand and WVGA(4.0) Emulator and IT works fine.But I got a complaint from one user that application is not working on HTC Desire V.

I don't have HTC Desire V device.Please help me to get emulator for HTC Phones and Motorola Phones(Add-ons for both phones).

Answer (score 0):

for HTC Desire V testing make WVGA with 512 RAM with ICS.

for Motorola create AVDs for any of these devices ATRIX2, DROIDRAZR, XT928, Droid4.Skins for these devices are already installed on your system it not update for SDK Manager, for before updating you see these inside API 10.

Comment: I created the Emulator for HTC with same configuration & my application is running there but not on real device..Please suggest any other alternative way..?

Comment: please specify the problem which is occurring on your device,like memory issue, unable to render views, MIN-SDK version or permission (in this case app will not install on that device) etc...

Comment: My android Application is force closing on real htc device but not On WVGA Emulator which has same configuration as of HTC desire.I don't have real device to test it and so I want find error through emulator.But I am not able to crate emulator having same configration as of HTC desire V.

Comment: Connect your device for USB debugging and check it check the crash report in logcat in case it is not appearing integrate Bugsense in your app to receive the crash reports.After looking at the crash report we can check which piece of code causing the error.